# Burying sheimos is a segula for a pandemic?

Tags: shemos-sacred-names, segulah, covid19-pandemic

Rabbi Moshe Heinemann, rav of the Agudah of Park Heights in Baltimore, gave a eulogy last week for the last two years of sheimos which they were burying, and mentioned that it is a segulah for a pandemic to end to bury sheimos. What is the idea behind this?

Answer (score 5):

See [Source for eulogizing for sheimos?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/116770/source-for-eulogizing-for-sheimos) for the 4 sources he brought for this. He finished the hesped with the following quote from the Sefer Mat'amim, p. 190 (couldn’t find the sefer on the Otzar Hachochma, so I am quoting from what I can make out from the recording):

> טעם למנהיג כשגונזים ספרים בלים וקרועים הן מספר תורה הן משאר ספרים,
> הולכים בהמון אל בית הקברות וגונזים שם בקרקע ועושים עליהם אוהל וסימן
> לידע ש(ינהגו?) (ב?)קדושה באותה מקום, והרב דורש, שעל פי רוב עושים זאת
> **בעת המגפה, רחמנא ליצלן**, והיא סגולה כדי לעורר רחמים בזה, כי כמו שאנו
> חסים על שמות ודברים שבקדושה, שלא ילכו לאיבוד, כן ירחם השם יתברך עלינו
> ועל בנינו שלא נלכו לאיבוד ולביזון כי גם אני משותפים בשמו הגדול: ישראל
> ואורייתא וקודשא בריך הוא חד הוא, ושמו משותף בינינו ואנו גם כן נקראים
> גוי קדוש, ואנו מבקשים מאת השמות הקדושים שירחמו עלינו בזכות שאנו מכבדים
> אותם.

> The reason for the custom that when they bury seforim (Hebrew
> books) which are worn and torn, whether it be a Torah scroll or other
> seforim, they go as a large crowd to the cemetery and bury them there
> in the ground, and make a tent over them and a sign to (so that others
> should) know that they should (conduct themselves?) (with?) holiness
> at that place. And teacher expounds (obviously referring to someone
> specific, unclear from this excerpt who), that the majority of the
> time they do this ***in the time of a plague, may The Merciful One
> save us***, and it is a segula (supernatural cure) in order to awaken
> Divine Mercy through this. Because, just like we are having compassion
> on the sheimos and articles of holiness – that they should go to
> destruction – so Hashem should have mercy on us and our children that
> we shouldn’t go to destruction and embarresment, because we too are
> partners with his holy name (just like the sheimos): The Jews and the
> Torah and The Holy One, Blessed Be Her are one, and his name is
> partnered among us, and we see are called a holy nation(i.e. we are
> called holy, just like “the articles of *holiness* and the sheimos are
> called holy), and we request from Hashem through these holy sheimos
> that He should have mercy on us in the merit that we are honoring
> them.